# Blackberry - Custom Grid layout

Tags: blackberry

I need to implement a custom Calendar similar Blackberry native Calendar. I need to mimic almost the same as we see Month view on native Calendar. I tried GridFieldManager, but that doesn't have that much flexibilities. I just went through this site and tried to mimic kind of Calendar view, but I am seeing problem that I need to display the grid lines in a different color and text inside the grids in a different color.

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_a_rich_UI_layout_with_TableLayoutManager.html?nodeid=1906675&vernum=0

Could you please share your thoughts and guide me?

thank you,
Ramesh S